# Can we make the import shorter for material-ui components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, material-ui

Is there a way to shortcut all this import into one?

I'm new to react but I always notice everything must be imported especially using CSS components.

Can you give me an idea how to shorten this?

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import NavigationIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Navigation';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your existing codebase to this option with material-ui [top-level-imports](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-codemod/README.md#top-level-imports) codemod

> Converts all `@material-ui/core` submodule imports to the root module

Install

```sh
npm install -D @material-ui/codemod
```

Script

```sh
find src -name '*.js' -print | xargs npx jscodeshift -t node_modules/@material-ui/codemod/lib/v4.0.0/top-level-imports.js
```

Result

```
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  ...
} from '@material-ui/core';
```

---

Refer to the document [minimizing-bundle-size](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/)

Comment: yeah i see that, but is it possible to do like import '@material-ui/core'

Comment: @DevelopmentStage The answer is NO, and if you use the editor like `VSCode`, the import should be done automatically, so it won't cost much. The only thing you need to do is format them in a kind you and your team perferred